# .NET 2.0: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: socket, windows-server-2000, .net

Scenario:

- I try to post a video to YouTube with the following code:

  YouTubeEntry createdEntry = service.Upload(newEntry);
- This works fine on my developer machine (running Windows XP).
- It fails on a Win2k server (running .NET 2.0) with the following error:

2010-07-15||01:14:08 PM||An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine||System||||   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
-->   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)

My Question:

> - How should I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and network monitor or wireshark. And who on earth is deploying new apps on win2k?

Comment: +1: It turns out that the firewall was interrupting the communication because I specified the wrong MIME type. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've seen stuff like this before and it is sometimes an app like Windows Firewall (ZoneAlarm, etc), but more often it's some sort of "internet security" app (ie anti-virus with a few extra bells and whistles).